# Ardor configuration settings to connect to remote node without downloading entire blockchain locally

Tags: nodes, full-node, nxt, ardor

What configuration is required to run the Ardor wallet software without downloading the entire blockchain, but only connect to a remote node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install and Ardor node then choose the light client option during installation or later set the following property to true in your nxt.properties file:

nxt.isLightClient=true